# ORA-06550: line 7, column 2: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SALE'

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SALE (OUTLETID    IN     NUMBER,
                                  itemCod     IN     NUMBER,
                                  START_Date  IN     DATE,
                                  END_DATE    IN     DATE,
                                  OUTLETID1      OUT NUMBER,
                                  itemCod1       OUT NUMBER,
                                  AMOUNT         OUT NUMBER,
                                  Quantity       OUT NUMBER,
                                  Entry_Date     OUT DATE)
IS
BEGIN
     SELECT l.OUTLET_ID,
            itemCode,
            SUM (Amount) Amount,
            SUM (quantity) Quantity,
            i.Entry_Date
       INTO OUTLETID1,
            itemCod1,
            AMOUNT,
            Quantity,
            Entry_Date
       FROM IDSTRANSACTION i
            JOIN lup_outlet l ON l.OUTLET_ID = i.outlet_id
            JOIN LUP Z ON Z.ZONE_ID = L.ZONE_ID
            JOIN prod p ON p.serial = itemCode
            JOIN lup_master m ON m.sup_id = p.Supplier_ID
      WHERE     l.OUTLET_ID IN (OUTLETID)
            AND itemCode IN (itemCod)
            AND TO_DATE (i.Entry_Date) BETWEEN START_Date AND END_DATE
   GROUP BY l.OUTLET_ID, itemCode, i.Entry_Date;
END;
```

---

```
DECLARE
   var   NUMBER;
   var1  NUMBER;
   var2  NUMBER;
   var3  NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SALE_PROCEDURE (OUTLETID    => 809,
                   itemCod     => 128169,
                   START_Date  => DATE '2018-01-01',
                   end_Date    => DATE '2019-01-01',
                   AMOUNT      => var,
                   Quantity    => var1,
                   OUTLETID1   => var2,
                   itemCod1    => var3);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.enable;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (var);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.enable;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (var1);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.enable;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (var2);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.enable;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (var3);
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Procedure expects 5 OUT parameters.

When calling it, you provided 4 variables. The last one, for the `entry_date` (`DATE` datatype) is missing. That would probably be

```
var4 DATE;
```